# Array - Undefined offset even if i already defined it

Tags: php, arrays

I have two pages, page 1 contains an array like this:

```
 $error=array();
 $error[]='First value';
 $error[]='Second value';
 $error[]='Third value';
```

page 2 is where I use those array values:

```
include 'page1.php';
echo '<p>'.$error[0].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$error[1].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$error[2].'</p>';
```

It should work, but instead it keeps showing the error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
Notice: Undefined offset: 2
```

Any idea?

Comment: It works fine for me... Do a var_dump(). Also, are you like voting up this question with alternate accounts?

Comment: are you not using the echo (or similar) to output those? is it simply a problem with the output code rather than the array?

Comment: well it works for me with this instead of your output code  'echo $error[0].$error[1].$error[2];'

Comment: Post your actual code then. I don't see any echo's in your question

Comment: How extensive are the pages? Can you post code for both pages?

Comment: Have you got another `$error` array in scope?

Comment: If you add a `print_r($error)` immediately after your `include('page1.php')` does it print anything?

Comment: @Rasclatt ,yes it says : Undefined variable: error

Comment: <p><?= $error[0] ?></p> should work assuming **valid** php structure. Your 'page 2', as shown, is **not** valid PHP.

Comment: Problem is likely on page 1 then. Is `$error` conditional? Is in inside an `if` `else` statement?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes,it is,i will make an edit and add the if statement too

Comment: You should then on your other page make a conditional `if(isset($error)) { do stuff }`

Comment: use: echo "<p>{$error[0]}</p>"; instead of echo '<p>$error[0]</p>';. Double quotes (") are interpolated, single quotes (') are literals.

Comment: @RyanVincent , they had a concatenation too...but i forgot to wrote them...sorry

Comment: Can you clean up the rest of your syntax in the post? It is making it difficult for us to help you as it is now.

Comment: @JayBlanchard , done .. im pretty sure its all good now

Comment: Are you POSTing `$error` to the second page?

Comment: One thing you should maybe think about doing is doing a multi-leveled error array with associative characteristics: `$error['email'][] = 'error text'`

Comment: @Rasclatt , so this is the problem??

Comment: actually i think i found the problem....seemed like indeed a foreach did it,also a multidimensional array would do it too

Comment: Phew! There you go! I think doing the multidimensional array will save you headaches for sure, then you can isolate where things are really giving you errors. One other thing you may want to look into is form validation through jQuery. It has a really good and easy to implement form validation library.

Comment: maybe,but i need to make this website code by code by myself,without boostrap or jquery.Else i will never manage to make a complete working website as i want to.Thanks a lot for your help,and sorry for wasting your time.Also thank you all guys

Comment: You should give @julianFresco the right answer if it was the `foreach` that helped you so other folks who come to this answer know that was what helped you out the most. Also other developers won't keep coming to your solved question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your updated question, it shows that

```
$error=array();
if( !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email']) ){
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error[] = 'Emailul nu este valid!'; 
      }else{ $email=$_POST['email']; }
 }else{ $error[]='Utilizatorul este obligatoriu!'; }
```

In your included file, you should check your conditional logic by doing var_dumps

`var_dump($_POST)` and look for the 'email' index.

Perhaps the condition that 'email' exists is not being satisfied!

**EDITED**, showing original below...

Often you'll find that it's less error-prone to use a foreach loop.

```
foreach($error as $err) {
  echo '<p>'.$err.'</p>';
}
```

Also, you may try using instead of `include file.php`, using `require('file.php')` or even `require_once('file.php')`

Comment: I dont want to use a loop here,and i already tried with require and require_once

Comment: @Petru then why don't you explicitly set your indexes?

Comment: If you don't want to use a foreach, then why not do $error[**0**]='First value';
$error[**1**]='Second value';
$error[**2**]='Third value';

Comment: Are you using a framework? Most frameworks will make use of an array called $errors or $error

Comment: You could try it as a debugging test. Also, have you not done a `var_dump($error); die;` like the other commenter asked?

Comment: oh... now i see.. i just did the var_dump and it says : array (size=0) empty .... how can it be empty?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please review the top portion. I hope it helps, because I have to run now.

Comment: Also, check what this evaluates to `!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: well,you were righ...it works with foreach...but i didnt wanted to use it...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Asside from what you have going on, you should maybe do a multi-dimentional associative array so errors are in categories like so:

```
$error['email'][] = 'error text';
$error['rparola'][] = 'error text';
```

Make your `$error` reporting conditional:

```
if(isset($error['email'])) { do stuff }
```

Comment: ironicaly,the error shows up when i am submitting the form,and as my if statement says,if the field is empty,shows up the $error,but instead of this,i get the offset error

Answer (score 0):

You have  a syntax Error in Your Code, that is why you have got that Error. 
I tried to be your debugger, Try it . Just modified your code.

```
echo '<td><input type=text name=email placeholder=Email value=</td>';
if(!empty($_POST['email']))
    echo $_POST['email'];
echo '<td>'.$error[1].$error[2].'</td>';  //Problem is here 

$error=array();
if( !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email']) ){
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error[] = 'Emailul nu este valid!'; 
      }else{ $email=$_POST['email']; }
 }else{ $error[]='Utilizatorul este obligatoriu!'; }
```

//Problem was here this $error[3] element on the index 3 was not assigned yet.

Comment: All his offsets are not working, not just the third. His array is empty when it gets to his display portion.